# eBay API call to findout if item is out of stock

Tags: python, api, python-requests, ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I am using the eBay developer APIs to scrape some books via the `findItemsByProduct` endpoint:

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/CallRef/findItemsByProduct.html

The only problem I am facing is that the response I receive does not tell me if the product is actually available or not.

E.g. JSON response I get from searching `9781492286738` is similar to a different call via `9780486433981` but whilst the former is actually available for purchase once I click on the url link contained in the response, the latter is actually out of stock:

https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Revolution-Betrayed-Trotsky-Leon-Paperback-Book-Cheap-Fast-Free-Post-/303078471909

[image]

Is there a way to make possibly a different call to see if the item is available? I've seen the Inventory endpoints but my understanding is that not relevant to my case as I am trying to check not my listings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `getItem` API for each item to get inventory

Comment: Can you please include example? I get
`'{"errorMessage":[{"error":[{"errorId":["2000"],"domain":["CoreRuntime"],"severity":["Error"],"category":["Request"],"message":["Service operation GetItem is unknown"],"subdomain":["Inbound_Meta_Data"],"parameter":[{"@name":"Param1","__value__":"GetItem"}]}]}]}'`
when trying to use getItem operation.

Comment: Adding headers I use in the request:
`"OPERATION-NAME": OPERATION_NAME,"SECURITY-APPNAME": SECURITY_APPNAME_KEY,"GLOBAL-ID": GLOBAL_ID,"RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT": "JSON","productId.@type": "ISBN","productId": isbn,"itemFilter.name": "Condition","itemFilter.value": "Used","sortOrder": "PricePlusShippingLowest",`
where:
`OPERATION_NAME = "GetItem"`

Comment: GetItem is is not part of finding API but part of Trading API that has a different rules, parameters and endpoint. Have no idea if SDK does manage it in same way: Sorry, never used the SDK

Comment: You can find instructions [Here](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getitem.html)